# HP Spectre x360 webcam is showing very low quality

Tags: webcam

I have a HP Spectre x360 laptop and I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. The webcam image is poor quality: the resolution is bad, if it's a little dark in a room it get's terrible quickly, and there is often a purple tinge to colours.

I think that it has been like this since I bought it a few years ago.

Is there a way I can play around with the settings somehow? Open to any other suggestions of how I could improve this. Thank you.

---

Update:

I downloaded `guvcview`, but playing with the settings didn't improve the webcam quality at all. Perhaps the webcam itself is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/spectrex360/comments/c4e26n/what_to_do_about_poor_webcam_resolution/
Looks like just tough-luck.